# Mysql_num_rows возвращает 0

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Вроде бы не новичок, но данную проблему решить не получается.
Составляю запрос. 
Но при посылке запроса через php, mysql_num_rows возвращает 0.
mysql_query("тут запрос") or die(mysql_error()) молчит и никаких ошибок не выводит.
Таблицы и поля все существуют, при тестировании через phpmyadmin получаю ожидаемый результат.
Может, кто сталкивался с подобным?

UPD:

```
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo ' count - '.count($r);
```

выводит всё правильно.

UPD2:

```
SELECT 
  Brand.Brand,
  Model.url,
  detail.id
FROM
  kuzov_link
  INNER JOIN detail ON (kuzov_link.id_detail = detail.id)
  INNER JOIN kuzov ON (kuzov_link.id_uzel = kuzov.id)
  INNER JOIN Model ON (kuzov.id_model = Model.IDModel)
  INNER JOIN Brand ON (Model.IDBrand = Brand.IDBrand)
WHERE
  detail.cod ='".$value."'
```

`COUNT(*)` не нужен. num_rows применяю для проверки, нашло ли что-то, так как в общем списке могут находится коды, которых нет в базе.

Comment: Код в студию.

Comment: @terantul - может быть вам надо использовать `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`?

Comment: У меня сегодня тоже что-то похожее было. Только вместо mysql_num_rows я использовал columnCount, который всегда возвращал 1, вне зависимости от реального результата. Так и не решил, использовал fetchAll.

Comment: А выводить mysql_errno() mysql_error() после запроса пробовали?